# Laravel user info not

Tags: php, laravel-5

In my api I say this:

```
public function internInfo($id)
{
   $user = User::where('EmployeeId','=',$id);
   dd($user->LastName);
}
```

The user is found but it can't get the LastName, but LastName exist!

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to take the results...Should be:

```
   $user = User::where('EmployeeId','=',$id)->first();
```